# using lambda to sort author names by surname

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, lambda

Ive been given a list of authors in a random order.
I need to remove the number before their name, and then print the names in alphabetical order by surname.

I can sort them by surname, but issues arise when there are more than one author, and no, I cannot write et al instead, i cannot change anything about the given authors string.

for example, it cannot sort "J. W. Han, M. Kamber" because there are two authors, it needs to only read the firs authors surname to sort it alphabetically.

Here's what i have so far:

```
authors = ["X. F. Li", "S. H. Lu", "X. A. Wang", "J. W. Han, M. Kamber", "S. Oyama, T. Ishida", "S. Haykin", "V. Vapnik", "A. Ragel, B. Cremilleux", "S. W. Zhu, W. Wong, D. B. Zhang, Y. Xiao, X. J. Chen"]
authors.sort(key=lambda name: name.split(" ")[-1].lower())


print(authors)
```

Comment: Split by `','`, use the first item returned, split it by `' '`, use the last item…?

Comment: @deceze how do you mean?

Comment: `authors.sort(key=lambda name: name.split(',')[0].split(" ")[-1].lower())`

Comment: What deceze means: `name.split(",")[0].split(" ")[-1]` - first split will always have at least one element (string without `,` will return a list only with the original string).

Comment: ahh, thank you, simple array sorting?

Comment: What if two authors have the same surname?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
out = sorted(inp, key=lambda authors: "".join(a.split()[-1] for a in authors.split(",")))
```

For example, given the input `inp`

```
inp = ["X. F. Li",
       "S. H. Lu",
       "X. A. Wang",
       "X. A. Wang, S. H. Lu",
       "S. H. Lu, X. A. Wang",
       "S. H. Lu, S. W. Zhu"]
```

the output `out` is

```
out = ["X. F. Li",
       "S. H. Lu",
       "S. H. Lu, X. A. Wang",
       "S. H. Lu, S. W. Zhu",
       "X. A. Wang",
       "X. A. Wang, S. H. Lu"]
```

Basically, you simply order the authors by the concatenation of their surnames.